# different output in Makefile rule

Tags: makefile, newline

In the following Makefile

```
f = echo $(1)

t:
    $(call f,"a \
        b"); \
    $(call f,"a \
        b")
```

- there is only one TAB, at the beginning of line 4 (the first call f)
- no blanks at the end of the lines

The output is

```
a b
a  b
```

The two calls are identical (except for the initial TAB). Why the output are different ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result.

Comment: GNU `make` 3.81 does not reproduce your result (tested on Mac OS X 10.8.3 with current XCode).

Comment: Reproduced with GNU Make 3.81 (on OS X 10.7.5) and vanilla 3.82, with 9 spaces before the `b")` on line 5; does not exhibit the problem with 8 or fewer.

Comment: I think this is a bug.  I've tried it with the latest version from Git and it still happens... John's comment is critical, though: you have to have 9 spaces at the beginning of the line not 8.  Please file a bug on Savannah about this: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=make

Comment: Yes: the problem happens with n > 8 blanks in line 5, it's ok if n <= 8 :-(

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer to why the output is different is that this is a small bug in GNU Make's backslash-newline whitespace collapsing.  The relevant code is in [`new_job()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/job.c#n2073):

```
/* Discard any preceding whitespace that has
   already been written to the output.  */
while (out > ref
       && isblank ((unsigned char)out[-1]))
   --out;
```

I don't know this code, but the `in` and `ref` pointers operate in lockstep, so comparing `out` to `ref` seems wrong.  Replacing `out > ref` with `out > cmds->command_lines[i]` corrects your problem and might not be a completely incorrect change to make to the code.

Whether this is a GNU Make bug or not, it's not really a great idea for your makefile to depend so intimately on the vagaries of whitespace removal.  If the whitespace is truly significant in your recipe, you could code this defensively as

```
f = echo $(strip $(1))
```

and avoid any problems at a stroke.

Comment: The example is not real, but only to highlight my problem. Real code is for a mylog subroutine just like `log = echo "\`$(now)\` [\`basename $(MAKE)\`($@)]" $(1) >> $(logf)` that I use passing a string. Sometimes the string argument is long and I break it with \.

Comment: @BraMo: the Make documentation doesn't describe in detail what happens to whitespace especially adjacent to \-escaped newlines, and different versions of make likely do it differently--definitely if this bug you have now reported gets fixed.  So unless you want your log output to depend on the Make version you happen to be using, it would be pragmatic to either avoid breaking even long string arguments with \ (even though that's ugly in your source) or to add `$(strip $(1))` to your `log` subroutine, thus pragmatically avoiding the problem.